# just one row from sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
import re
from sqlalchemy import *

db = create_engine('sqlite:///code.db')

db.echo = True

metadata = MetaData(db)

halo4 = Table('emblem_codes', metadata, autoload=True)

#########################
## Get One Unused Code ##
#########################

s = select([halo4.c.code, halo4.c.status=='None'])
result = s.execute()

for row in result:
    print row
```

My code returns all 80999 results. I only want one. Whats the best way to do this?

This a sample of code.db:

```
(u'JRQRY-MYHW3-D67GR-7YWFF-CRJ31', None)
(u'9D7DR-4WFDY-VG49F-3DYCG-7DYT5', None)
(u'QR9WT-P3CTM-PW4WW-34JJ4-RFKV7', None)
(u'7FMXQ-H97TC-FFYC6-XHXFV-Y7KR2', None)
(u'VKHXW-29WC4-4PF4Y-2QMJ4-4W2H4', None)
```

Comment: I don't know how to use `first()`

Comment: The first one in a sort.

Comment: Any of them really. I'm already returning all rows with status of None. I just need one row returned vs all rows.

Comment: It's hard to try this without your data. But SqlAlchemy maps index access to limits, so you should be able to do `result[0]`.

Comment: @keith updated to include sample code.

Answer (score 29):

If you want to get just one row from a [ResultProxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy) object (which is the result of your `s.execute()` statement, you need to use the [`fetchone()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy.fetchone) method:

```
s = select([halo4.c.code, halo4.c.status=='None'])
result = s.execute()
one_row = result.fetchone()
another_row = result.fetchone()
```